# Python regular expression for substring

Tags: python, regex

All I want is to grab the first 3 numeric characters of string:

```
st = '123_456'
import re
r = re.match('([0-9]{3})', st)
print r.groups()[0]
```

1. Am I doing the right thing for grabbing first 3 characters?
2. This returns `123` but what if I want to get the first 3 characters regardless of numbers and alphabets or special characters?

When given `12_345`, I want to grab only `12_`

Thanks,

Comment: If you just want to grab the first three characters of a string, string slicing will suffice. If you want to grab the first three numbers, your regex sort of works. (It will grab the first three numbers next to each other. From `'12_345_678'` it should grab `'345'`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are really close, just drop the extra set of parenthesis and use the proper indexing of zero instead of one.  Python indexing starts at zero.  See below.

This works:

```
import re
mystring = '123_456'
check = re.search('^[0-9]{3}', mystring)
if check:
    print check.group(0)
```

the ^ anchors to the beginning of the string which will ensure a match to the first three numeric digits only.  If you do not use the carrot the regexp will match any three digits in a row in the string.

Some may suggest \d but this includes more than 0-9.

As others will surely point out a simple substring operation will do the trick if all the fields start with three numeric digits that you want to extract.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If you always need first three characters in a string, then you can use the below:

```
first_3_charaters = st[:3]
```

There is no need of regular expression in your case.

Answer (score 0):

If all digits are separated by `_`, then you can simply use this regular expression which greedily matches all numeric characters before the first `_` .

```
r = re.match('([0-9]*)_', st)
```

Actually, the `_` in this RE is not necessary，so you can simplify it to (so that any separator is accepted ):

```
r = re.match('(\d*)', st)
```

**But** this solution will give you `1234` if `st = '1234_56'`. I'm not sure whether it is your intention.

So, if you want **at most 3 numeric characters**, you can just modify the regular expression to:

```
r = re.match('(\d{,3})', st)
```